# JavaScript Converting 'Thu May 06 2021 15:26:32 GMT-0400' to 'MM/DD/YYYY 00:00 AM/PM'

Tags: javascript, date, sorting, filter

For Date Comparison, I have an object that returns a date in this format:

```js
Thu May 06 2021 17:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
```

How would I go about translating this date into this format?

```js
 05/06/2021 5:00 PM
```

Comment: If you're doing Date _Comparison_ you want to work with date _Objects_ or raw timestamps — you shouldn't care about the display format. If your object "returns a date in this format" you should parse it into a Date object or, if you can, change the return type to a Date instead of a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do this. You could pass that string to the `Date` constructor, after dropping the time zone information. But it is not guaranteed by the specification that the date string will be interpreted correctly as it is not ISO 8601 compliant (See [Date Time Format in ECMAScript spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-date-time-string-format)).

So to have full control over the conversion, you could just apply string manipulation without using the `Date` constructor:

```js
const formatDate = str =>
    str.replace(/\w+ (\w+) (\d+) (\d+) (\d+):(\d+).*/, (_, M, d, y, h, m) =>
        `${
            1+"JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec".indexOf(M)/3
        }/${d}/${y} ${h % 12 || 12}:${m} ${"AP"[+(+h > 11)]}M`
        .replace(/\b\d\//, "0$&")
    );

// Demo
let s = "Thu May 06 2021 17:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)"
let result = formatDate(s);

console.log(result);
```